# Axios interceptor doesnt immediately navigate to error page with `useNavigation`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, interceptor

I use `axios` in my `React` project. In the interceptor when I find server error, I navigate to error page with `useNavigate`. My code looks like this.

```js
export const AxiosInstanceProvider: FC<AxiosInstanceProviderProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const responseInterceptorId = instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error: AxiosError) => {
      const status = error.response?.status;
      if (!status || isServerError(status)) {
        navigate("/error", {
          state: {
            error,
          },
        });
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

    return function cleanup() {
      instance.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptorId);
    };
  }, [navigate]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

The problem is that it navigates to the page, but still goes to the `catch` block which, for example, shows snackbar, and this snackbard starts appearing on error page, or throws Error on screen that I have defined in component. The means it doest'n navigate immediately, as I was expecting.